# How does the flow of execution go in nested if/else statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

If I have two if statements and then an else, how do I know which if statement the else applies to? Is it by the indentation? For example this,

```
if x == 2:
    if y == 3:
        x = y
else:
    y = x
```

Which if statement does the else refer to?

Comment: In python, it will be indents.  Other languages use curly braces.  What you're looking for is called 'scope'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else` applies to the first `if` statement, see the indentation.

Comment: And if the else were indented to match the second if, it would apply to that if?

Comment: @Sygnerical yes. You know you can try these things out in the interpreter?

Comment: ya, if the else is intended according to the second if then it applies to the second.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm on a phone right now, no access to a computer

Comment: @Sygnerical so, given that you can't act on it, why ask?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i was curious and just wanted to make sure. I'm reading a pdf about python and it  didn't explain that bit

Answer (score 3):

You gotta look at the indentation to figure out to what which `if` does that `else` belong to.

In this case

```
if x == 2:
|    if y == 3:
|    |    x = y
|    |
|    else:
|         pass # example
else:
    y = x
```

it belongs to the `if x = 2:`

Answer (score 2):

First, the above code checks:

```
if x == 2:
```

If this boolean is `False`, the code moves to the `else`:

```
else:
     y = x
```

If `if x == 2` is `True`, the code moves to the nested `if-statement`:

```
if y == 3:
     x = y
```

According to this page http://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php, it talks about how instead of braces to group statements into blocks, Python uses indentation: "Python programs get structured through indentation, i.e. code blocks are defined by their indentation."

---

[image: idk]
<sub>(source: [python-course.eu](http://www.python-course.eu/images/blocks.png))</sub>
 
tl;dr: **YES, in Python, indentation matters.**